# Ag-grid - Data does not load in laravel view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, ag-grid

I am using `Laravel Framework 5.7.19` and the latest version of [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-getting-started/).

I am loading the needed libraries from the example in my `app.blade.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- ag-grid -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.min.noStyle.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    @include('layouts.nav.mainNav')

    <main class="py-4">
        @yield('content')
    </main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My `grid.blade.php` looks like the following:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="">

                <h1>Hello from ag-grid!</h1>
                <button onclick="getSelectedRows()">Get Selected Rows</button>
                <div id="myGrid" style="height: 600px;width:500px;" class="ag-theme-balham"></div>

                <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
                    // specify the columns
                    var columnDefs = [
                        {headerName: "Make", field: "make", rowGroupIndex: 0 },
                        {headerName: "Price", field: "price"}
                    ];

                    var autoGroupColumnDef = {
                        headerName: "Model",
                        field: "model",
                        cellRenderer:'agGroupCellRenderer',
                        cellRendererParams: {
                            checkbox: true
                        }
                    }

                    // let the grid know which columns and what data to use
                    var gridOptions = {
                        columnDefs: columnDefs,
                        enableSorting: true,
                        enableFilter: true,
                        autoGroupColumnDef: autoGroupColumnDef,
                        groupSelectsChildren: true,
                        rowSelection: 'multiple'
                    };

                    // lookup the container we want the Grid to use
                    var eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');

                    // create the grid passing in the div to use together with the columns & data we want to use
                    new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);

                    fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/ly7d1').then(function(response) {
                        return response.json();
                    }).then(function(data) {
                        gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);
                    })

                    function getSelectedRows() {
                        const selectedNodes = gridOptions.api.getSelectedNodes()
                        const selectedData = selectedNodes.map( function(node) { return node.data })
                        const selectedDataStringPresentation = selectedData.map( function(node) { return node.make + ' ' + node.model }).join(', ')
                        alert('Selected nodes: ' + selectedDataStringPresentation);
                    }
                </script>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

It is basically the simple example from the [Ag-grid JS example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-getting-started/).

[image]

The data does not load within the example. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look at the example that you're referring to, I tried replicating some part of it, for loading the data, the libraries need to be in the same blade file that you use for loading the data, so add this in your grid.blade.php:

```
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.min.noStyle.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css">
```

This is the only thing I could come up with looking at the example. Hope this helps.

P.S: I was able to implement the example this way exactly, though I couldn't understand why 2 blade files are being used here, any specific reason for the same?